# import javafx.scene.control.Label error

Tags: java, javafx

I created an application using javafx. I added `jfxrt.jar` to the class path but it gives at the time of importing scene class. I am using jdk 1.8.0.91 how I resolve this problem. I am new to javafx.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
```

Comment: What error message? Also, JavaFX8 is part of JDK8 so I don't understand the part of the question about jfxrt.jar.

Comment: It is import error of scene class.When I searched I got solution of adding jfxrt.jr which is present in jdk lib

Comment: If you have an error on this line, that means that the JavaFX package is not present on the classpath, which is impossible if you are using Java8 (as you state) as it contains the JavaFX package by default.

Comment: show us some error log